# Редирект со страницы WordPress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста понять, почему при переходе по ссылке на блог из хедера, происходит редирект на несуществующую страницу (ошибка 404). [image: Кнопка блога][image: Собственно, сама ошибка]
Раньше, до появления этой ошибки, при переходе на страницу блога отображадся список опубликованных статей, а сейчас перекидывает на несуществующую страницу. В настройках страниц вроде бы нет ничего о редиректах. Сама страница блога всегда была полностью пустой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 [Вот ссылка на сам сайт](http://vladakazakova.ru/)
Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: У вас 301 редирект с /blog на /proshlyie-zhizni/ http://take.ms/uWoq6 Ищите, где вы его поставили, в плагинах, nginx или apache.

Comment: И вообще-то blog - это должна быть категория, а не страница.